# Gear for climbing a building

Tags: climbing

What gear do I need to climb buildings? Can I use a suction cup lifters? Or is it a safety risk, since this piece of equipment was clearly not developed to climb buildings?

Comment: Google: [Alain Robert](https://www.google.ca/search?q=climbing+buildings&safe=active&espv=2&biw=1325&bih=1100&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQkbb25bfQAhVH92MKHY3UArAQ_AUIBygA&dpr=1#safe=active&q=alain+robert).

Comment: VTC it would be very specific to the building.  For sure not going to climb a brick building with suction cups.

Comment: Buildings aren't normally climbed, except by crooks and thrill seekers. Anyone with business on the outside of the building either accesses it from descending off the top of the building by ropes, or by erecting scaffolds.

Comment: I know what buildering is, I buildered all over Calgary in the middle of the night when I was younger, *but* it was undoubtabley tresspassing (crooks, even though we did no damage and left no trace) and we were doing it for fun (thrill seeking).  Buildering is nothing more than bouldering on buildings, so you use the same gear. But if you want to do building-aid climbing with suction cups, those cups can hold up a 200lbs sheet of glass, so they can probably also hold your weight. Just don't get caught.

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole industry of commercial rope access for maintenance etc and the techniques used are related but not identical to recreational climbing and mountaineering. There are also a few individuals who climb buildings for recreation/self promotion.

In the commercial  case it is usually more about descending from an well established top anchor rather than actual climbing as such.

One problem is that climbing a building without permission will probably be illegal.

[Alain Robert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Robert) is famous for unauthorised climbs of public buldings but he tends to 'free climb' and it has to be emphasised that this is both illegal and very dangerous. Even he  tends to choose structure which are massive, boring ladders.

Equally climbing a bilding is likely to be failry tedious as you would want to be absolutely certain that it was within your capabilities (or you will die) and it will just be executing the same moves again and again until you get to the top or fall off  so I'm not sure thre is really that much to reccomend it.

And as it has now been done before there isn't even that much celebrity to be gained.